# Beamerarticle: Unexpected selection of overlay

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

Consider the following MWE:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}<1-2|article:2>
       \only<1|article:1>{Foo}

       \only<2|article:2>{Bar}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would expect that I get a page with "Bar". However, I get "Foo" instead. Is my expectation incorrect (if so: why?), or is it a bug?